# Help understanding domains of two variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am confused by this topic.

Example: For the first one, I feel like I'd set the inner  section to 0, because I know that you can't take the natural log of zero. I just am not sure how to correlate the inequalities with the graphs.

---

[image]

Comment: Can you take the natural log of a negative number?

Comment: no
/13characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a process of elimination.

(4) has a domain of $(-\infty,\infty)$, since it is the equation of a line.

(1) Mike noted this answer, for ln(w), w>0

(3) Note that $\sqrt{x^2y^3} = xy^\frac{3}{2} = x(\sqrt{y})^3$, can you take the square root of a negative number if we're talking about real valued functions?

(2) Follows from the above three.

Answer (score 1):

1. $\ln(w)$ is only defined for $w>0$, so the first function is only defined when $3x + 2y>0$. This is an area above or below a line. Which one?
2. $e^{w}$ is defined for all $w\in \mathbb{R}$, but $\frac{1}{v}$ is only defined for $v\neq 0$. This means, the second function is defined for all $x,y$ except for those with $3x+2y=0$.
3. $\sqrt{w}$ is only defined for $w \geq 0$, so $x^2y^3$ needs to be nonnegative. Since $x^2$ is always nonnegative, we need to exclude nonnegative values of $y^3$, or equivalently, those of $y$.
4. This is defined for every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

Does this information help you to identify the graphs?